# What is a singlet, doublet and quartet of a root?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

The following is taken from Lie Algebras in Particle Physics, page 118. Can someone please explain to me what is a *doublet under $\alpha^2$*, *quartet under $\alpha^1$* and other similar terms?

[image]

Comment: Would be interesting, but is it a wild guess that those terms might be explained on previous pages in that book? Have you looked there?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've read all the pages in before this and those terms weren't explained. I did a keyword search for _singlet_, _doublet_ and couldn't find any.

Comment: OK, those could just be words for certain chains or tuples. The clip starts with "Let us illustrate this ...". Maybe can you add "this", i.e. whatever theorem or proposition or lemma right before is supposed to be illustrated with this example?

Comment: It sounds like the passage is describing $\alpha$-chains through $\beta$ (with $\alpha$, $\beta$ roots in a root system). The root system $G_2$ has $\alpha$-chains of length four, when $\alpha$ is a short root. That could be what's called a quartet here. Somewhat non-standard if you ask me, but physicists often use different notation in Lie algebras and representation theory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I got the idea now. When he mentioned "bottom of $\alpha^1$ quartet", he meant that we can still apply $E_\alpha^1$ 3 times before annihilating the state.